# How to find the number of arrays within an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For an assignment I have to draw a (fixed) number of words on the screen with separation between them, and on multiple rows, like this:

```
Gobject
GLabel    GLine    GOval    GRect
Row3
```

I want to make it more dynamic, so that I could just make an array of arrays so that when I change this array, the number of rows and words per row will also change. My first sub-question is, how is this normally done? Is creating an array of arrays the way you would normally do this? My idea here is that I want to minimize hard-coding, and an array of arrays seems to hold all the information I need. (the number of rows, and words per row).

My idea:

```
String[][] labels = {{"GObject"}, {"GLabel", "GLine", "GOval", "GRect"}, {"Row3"}}
```

I know that `GObject` is on the 1st row, alone. `GLabel` is with `Gline`, `GOval`, `GRect` on the next row, and `Row3` on the final row. **How do I get this information out?**

I know how to get the number of elements within each row:

```
labels[2].length //this equals 1, which is true
```

I don't know yet how to get the number of rows out of the array of arrays. If I know that, I can create two for loops and draw everything conveniently on the screen, without needing to change anything but the array itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`labels.length` is the number of rows in the array of arrays.

As for using arrays, an array is not the most dynamic structure, since its size is fixed. If you initialize the array statically as in your question, there's no problem, but if you read the input from some file and don't know the size of the array in advance, it might be better to use a List of Lists - `List<List<String>>` - which is not fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    // each lables[i] is an array.
    System.out.println("length = " + labels[i].length + " for row " + i);
}
```